# Load file and copy it and save to new folder?

Tags: java

How can I copy a file and save it to a new specified folder?

```
String pathOne = "path";
File file1 = new File(pathOne);

String pathTwo = "path";
```

save file1 to new directory

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons library. It has FileUtils class that makes that kind of operations easy

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

in your case copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile) function is what you are looking for